# Why is this question about creating a second instagram account off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[How can I create a second instagram account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110832/how-can-i-create-a-second-instagram-account/110836#110836)

The question clearly requires some operation in Android, either setting up new android profiles, or using a particular software. Is questions about android apps not on topic here?

Comment: Al's answer and eldarerathis' comment are dead on. It's not "clear" at all that a platform-independent third party service with web access to its content requires signing up through the app. I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 2):

That one seems a bit borderline to me.

The reason used, "Questions which are Android-independent...are off-topic..." is technically correct. I'd expect that Instagram in iOS would act the same way.

But it's also not like you can go to the website and create an account; you can only create an account by installing the app.

So *I* think the question is fine here, even if the answer is probably "you can't".

Comment: I imagine this is probably the reason people voted to close it. In particular, anyone who is not familiar with Instagram (I am personally not; I had to look this up) may not realize that your account is connected to the app directly. A bit of elaboration on the account creation process may be useful for this particular question, to highlight why it is directly tied to the app/Android and not just a question about Instagram as a service.

Comment: Agreed. I think I voted to close this question as I was unaware that you can only create accounts via the app. Given that this is the case, I see why it was posted here and that it does in fact appear to be on-topic.